# Optimization of Top-N and last-N in one query

Tags: sql, postgresql

In RDBMS PostgreSQL 12.8 I have one table (to simplicity I've omitted several columns):

figure (~3.5 millions rows)

```
id       
----
1    
2   
...
```

and another table

figure_step (~20 rows for one figure, in total ~70 millions rows)

```
id  figure_id  number status       
--------------------------
1   1          1      'FINISHED'
2   1          2      'STARTED'
3   2          1      'FINISHED'
4   2          2      'DELAYED'
5   2          3      'CANCELLED'
...
```

I have query that selects top-1-by-number step in 'DELAYED' status and last-1-by-number step in 'FINISHED' status for figure:

```sql
SELECT * FROM figure f
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT * FROM figure_step fs
                   WHERE fs.status = 'DELAYED' AND f.id = fs.figure_id
                   ORDER BY number ASC
                   LIMIT 1) step_one
    ON step_one.figure_id = f.id
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT * FROM figure_step fs
                   WHERE fs.status 'FINISHED' AND f.id = fs.figure_id
                   ORDER BY number DESC
                   LIMIT 1) step_two
    ON step_two.figure_id = f.id
WHERE ...
LIMIT ... OFFSET ...
```

`WHERE` clause selects about 19000 rows from ~3.5 million rows with `LIMIT` about 150 rows. Keyword `lateral` used here to prevent joining big tables `figure` and `figure_step`.
So, I have two questions:

1. Is it appropriate to use `lateral` here? I think so, because without it we need to join `figure_step` two times using left join.
2. Here we join `figure_step` two times with lateral join. Are there any ways to optimize this, for example, reuse part of the subquery?

Comment: You need to tag the specific DBMS you're using. Based on the `LATERAL` keyword, I'm guessing it's PostgreSQL v9.3 or later.

Comment: @RichardDeeming thanks, I've added PostgreSQL 12.8

Comment: Without ORDER BY, what is OFFSET supposed to achieve?  How selective is your WHERE?

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably wrong about this, and misunderstand the importance of that number.
But maybe one lateral might be enough.
By using conditional aggregation, instead of the double order & limit.

```
... 
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT 
      MIN(CASE WHEN fs.status = 'DELAYED'  THEN fs.id END) MinDelayedId
    , MAX(CASE WHEN fs.status = 'FINISHED' THEN fs.id END) MaxFinishedId
    FROM figure_step fs
    WHERE f.id = fs.figure_id
) step
...
```